# How to chain "OR" dynamically with Squeel

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to generate `LIKE` match with `OR` combination, which is specified by given queries dynamically.

I can realize that in native ruby like this:

```
scope :name_search, -> search {
  # search = { keywords: "foo bar, any" }
  if search[:keywords].present?
    keywords = []
    search[:keywords].to_s.split(/[\s,]/).map do |k|
      keywords.push("name LIKE '%#{k}%'") if k.present?
    end
    return where(keywords.join(" OR "))
  end
}
```

and the result is `SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (name LIKE '%foo%' OR name LIKE '%bar%' OR name LIKE '%any%')`.
Good, this is what I want.

But, how to realize the same thing with using `squeel`?

I (want to) believe there is already an easier way to do the same thing.

Or, if using `arel` is easier than `squeel` to realize this, I would use `arel`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `Squeel` documentation, you can do something like this:

```
names = []
search[:keywords].to_s.split(/[\s,]/).map do |k|
  names << "#{k}%"
end
User.where{name.like_any names}
```

Link to the github repo where you can find this information:
https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel#compound-conditions